# I can't solve $\left\{x^2\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-2\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right\}u\left(x,y\right)=x\left(x+u\right)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$\left\{x^2\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-2\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right\}u\left(x,y\right)=x\left(x+u\right)$

For

$\left\{x^2\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-2\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right\}u\left(x,y\right)=0$

I get

$u\left(x,y\right)=\Phi \left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)$

Thus let $a=x;\:b=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$

Then I end up (after substituting with a and b in the first and original equation with x(x+u)) with

$a^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}-\frac{\partial\:u}{\partial\:b}\left(\left(b-\frac{1}{a}\right)^2-3\right)=a\left(a+u\right)$

So what now? It was suggested to me to take this kind of substitution for this exercises but it does not seem to work here... What can I do now?

Comment: Firstly, please, do not delete question for some time after posting, because during I was writing answer to your previous one, it's disappear and all my formulas vanish .. frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Your homogeneous solution is wrong. It gives

$$
u_h(x,y) = \Phi\left(y-\frac 2x\right)
$$

now changing variables according to

$$
\cases{
a = x\\
b = y-\frac 2x
}
$$

we transform

$$
\left\{x^2\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-2\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right\}u\left(x,y\right)=x\left(x+u\right)\Rightarrow a u_a = u+a
$$

with solution

$$
u(a,b) = a\left(\ln a + \Psi(b)\right)
$$